# SQL: Dúvida no Relacionamento entre Tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, query, pl-sql

Estou criando um sistema académico que consiste em um tipo de cardápio de restaurante virtual, para isso, criei três tabelas no banco:

Tabela de Itens do Cardápio:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEMS(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DESCRICAO VARCHAR(20),
    PRECO FLOAT NOT NULL
)
```

Tabela de Pedidos:

```
CREATE TABLE PEDIDO(
    NUMERO INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    MESA INT NOT NU NULL,
    VALORTOTAL FLOAT
)
```

Tabela onde registro os Itens do Pedido, no qual:

> ```
> ID_PEDIDO = FK de Pedido,
> ID_ITEM = FK de Item
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM_PEDIDO(   
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ID_PEDIDO INT NOT NULL,
    ID_ITEM INT NOT NULL,
    QTD_ITEM INT
 )
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

No sistema, o usuário poderá escolher um **item** ou mais para seu **pedido**, assim como a quantidade deste item. Ao final do pedido, deverá retornar o **preço** total do mesmo.

> Sendo assim, devo deixar a QTD_ITEM na tabela ITEM_PEDIDO? 
>   Quanto ao PREÇO, devo deixar na tabela ITEM ou incluo também na tabela  ITEM_PEDIDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo que é relacionado ao que foi/será comprado deve ficar dentro da tabela `ITEM_PEDIDO` se for relacionado ao `ITEM`. Sendo assim o `PRECO`, como é do `ITEM` e não tem relação com o pedido, deve ser colocado na tabela `ITEM` e a `QTD_ITEM` que tem relação com o que foi consumido deverá estar na tabela `ITEM`. O cálculo do valor total será o seguinte:

```
SELECT P.NUMERO,
       SUM(IP.QTD_ITEM * I.PRECO) AS VALOR_TOTAL
  FROM PEDIDO P
       INNER JOIN ITEM_PEDIDO IP ON IP.ID_PEDIDO ON P.NUMERO
       INNER JOIN ITEMS I ON I.ID = IP.ID_ITEM
 WHERE P.NUMERO = 'X'
 GROUP BY P.NUMERO
```

Caso queira manter um preço histórico de `ITEM`, sugiro a criação de uma tabela com os preços com a data vigente da seguinte forma:

```
╔════════════════════════════╗
║         ITEM_PRECO         ║
╠═════════════════╦══════════╣
║ ID_ITEM         ║ INTEIRO  ║
║ INICIO_VIGENCIA ║ DATA     ║
║ FINAL_VIGENCIA  ║ DATA     ║
║ PRECO           ║ NUMÉRICO ║
╚═════════════════╩══════════╝
```

E a adição da coluna `DATA_PEDIDO` na tabela `PEDIDO`. Sendo assim o cálculo ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT P.NUMERO,
       SUM(IP.QTD_ITEM * IP.PRECO) AS VALOR_TOTAL
  FROM PEDIDO P
       INNER JOIN ITEM_PEDIDO IP ON IP.ID_PEDIDO ON P.NUMERO
       INNER JOIN ITEMS I ON I.ID = IP.ID_ITEM
       INNER JOIN ITEM_PRECO IP ON IP.ID_ITEM = I.ID
                               AND P.DATA_PEDIDO BETWEEN IP.INICIO_VIGENCIA AND IP.FINAL_VIGENCIA
 WHERE P.NUMERO = 'X'
 GROUP BY P.NUMERO;
```

Assim você poderá fazer alterações de preço sem maiores problemas e sem precisar replicar dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sorack! Me ajudou muito!
Agora só me resta uma dúvida:
No JAVA, eu tenho uma classe para cada seção do cardápio.
Por exemplo: Uma classe para Bebidas, outra para Saladas, outra para Sobremesas e assim por diante.
Posso deixar no banco uma tabela única para elas, que é o caso da tabela ITEM, ou deverei "subdividir" esta ITEM em várias tabelas, tais como: TABELA BEBIDAS, TABELA SALADAS, etc.
Para cada classe no JAVA, necessariamente preciso de uma tabela?

Comment: @EduardoR não necessariamente. Se os atributos forem iguais e só o comportamento diferente não vejo porque criar várias tabelas.

Comment: Foi o que pensei mesmo, @Sorack! Obrigado por sanar minha dúvida.

Answer (score -1):

> Quanto ao PREÇO, devo deixar na tabela ITEM ou incluo também na tabela ITEM_PEDIDO?

Inclua também na tabela ITEM_PEDIDO.

A tabela ITEMS contém qual é o preço vigente para cada item. Já para cada item de pedido deve-se manter tanto a quantidade de unidades pedidas como também qual era o preço vigente no momento do pedido. E o motivo é bem simples: os preços variam ao longo do tempo.

Suponha que o item A tenha preço $10 no dia D1 e que no dia D2 tenha o preço $20. Se um pedido P1 de 3 unidades para o item A foi realizado no dia D1, então o valor do pedido, para esse item, foi de $30. Se o valor do preço do item ficar armazenado somente na tabela ITEMS e se no dia D2 for consultar quanto foi o valor do pedido P1, a consulta retornará $60 para o item A, o que está errado! Por isso que nos sistemas comerciais de pedidos para cada item sempre é armazenado o valor unitário do item no momento do pedido.

Observação adicionais:

- não utilize tipo de dados `float` para armazenar valores monetários;
- na tabela ITEM_PEDIDO não é necessário criar uma coluna específica
  para ser a chave primária. A chave usual é {ID_PEDIDO, SEQ_ITEM}, onde SEQ_ITEM é um número sequencial, para cada pedido.

Comment: @EduardoR: Fique atento ao detalhe que o preço de cada item é temporal.